# Angularjs ui-router resolve in route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise, resolve

Could you check my code:

```
    .state('addNewGroup', {
    url: '/group/new',
    resolve:{
        "checkPermission": function ($state, checkPermission) {
            checkPermission.checkPermission()
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        alert('Hello');
                    } else {
                        alert('access denied');
                    }
                })
        },
        "otherStuff": function () {
            console.log("Should execute only if result in 'checkPremission' is true");
        }

    },
});
```

**PROBLEM**

I two promises in the routing configuration.
Is it possible to resolve only specific promise?
Let's suppose I have 5 promises to resolve and I want to resolve them all only if "checkPremission" is true. In other cases I don't want to resolve it all.
Is it possible or I should use different logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the next promise wait for the previous one by injecting it as a dependency:

```
resolve: {
  firstResolve: function() {
    return 'A result';
  },
  nextResolve: function(firstResolve) {
    // firstResolve has the value 'A result' here
  }
}
```

Technically, the second resolve will execute, but you can base your logic on the result of the first one.

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that when you write code like this, I think that all the functions (after the key) is executed asynchronously. But as I saw (if true), you have to wait for the result to decide what is the next action. So, why don't you put your code (may be if-else) to decide the functions which would be called in the successful and failed function of promise.